# How to I require a parameter on a method has a certain Annotation?

Tags: java, class, annotations, command, public

So what i'm looking for is if there is anyway you can make a `@Annotation` require a method to have a parameter.

What I mean by this is if you have a method with a `@Command` it requires the method its over to have a parameter of `IssuedCommand`

Like this

`@Command public void command(IssuedCommand cmd) {}` < It requires IssuedCommand to be there, if not there will be a error.

Is there anyway this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At compilation time or run time?

Comment: I want it in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example using reflection

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get all methods
        for (Method method : Driver.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            // get your annotation
            Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(Command.class); // reference could be of type Command if you want
            if (annotation != null) {
                // check if parameter exists
                List<Class> parameterTypes = new ArrayList<Class>(Arrays.asList(method.getParameterTypes()));
                if (!parameterTypes.contains(IssuedCommand.class)) {
                    System.out.println("trouble");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Command
    public void command(IssuedCommand cmd) {

    }

    public static class IssuedCommand {}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface Command {}
}
```

You use reflection to get the specific method you want to check. You can do this by checking if the method is annotated. You can then compare the types in the method's parameter list.